# Best model for various bad situations

Tags: correlation, variance, predictive-models, heteroscedasticity

"What type of predictive model would best handle a wide  variety of data issues.

1. Extreme heteroscedasticity
2. bi or tri modal distribution’s
3. heavily correlated predictors…

Saw this as an Amazon Research Scientist interview question.

What are good answers to this? My gut feel would have been to fix the problems first.

Comment: 1) What has extreme heteroscedasticity? // 2) What distributions are multimodal? // 3) There are a bunch of ways to address this; principal component regression (PCR/PCA), partial least squares (PLS), and penalized regression are three examples. // What are your thoughts on these? There's no one right answer. The idea for asking this to a research scientist applicant, who probably has a PhD and some professional experience, is to have a technical discussion.

Comment: @Dave my idea was to remove the problem before the model, but given the question I was expecting somebody to have a answer to this that I had not thought of

Comment: So how would you remove the problems?

Comment: @Dave 1) rescaling the variables 2) possibly use something like gaussian mixture model 3) pca, remove one of the correlated predictors, combine the predictors